# Visual Studio Express 2012 : Windows Phone 7 ->Upgrade to windows phone8 ( Windows.Phone.Controls.Toolkit)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wptoolkit

We have a app which works on Windows Phone 7.1. We recently changed it to 8.0. After changing to 8.0 it started giving below error.

Checked in nuGet. wptoolkit is updated and installed.

error : Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue with below answer from mSpot Inc
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f4fb6ea7-417b-41a6-9239-a917c35d1dc7/visual-studio-express-2012-windows-phone-7-upgrade-to-windows-phone8-?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required

First make sure the Toolkit is completely removed from your solution and project.

Using NuGet, uninstall the Toolkit
Check the project Reference folder. If it still has a reference to the Toolkit, delete it.
In Windows, look for the packages folder in your solution folder. If you aren't using any other NuGet packages, delete the packages folder.
Delete any Toolkit dll files in the solution and project subfolders.
Then reinstall the Toolkit with NuGet.